# Importar modulos python desde otro directorio

Tags: python, python-import

Estuve buscando por todo internet, intenté todas las formas posibles y aún no puedo importar el módulo que necesito. El arbol de mi proyecto es este:

code
├── carpeta1
│   ├── subcarpeta 1
│       ├── archivo1.py (archivo a importar)
│── carpeta2
│       └── main.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es muy elegante, pero al menos es la única forma que encontré partiendo de una carpeta hacía atrás:

```
import sys

sys.path.append("..")
from carpeta1.subcarpeta1.archivo1 import *
```

En tu caso, `main.py` en la `carpeta2` quiere importar un módulo que físicamente y relativo a `main.py` se encuentra en: `../carpeta1/subcarpeta1/archivo1.py`, por lo que agregamos al `path` la carpeta `root`de tu proyecto con `sys.path.append("..")`, ten en cuenta que si lo hicieras de un nivel más profundo deberías hacer `sys.path.append("../..")`. Con esto, ya es posible hacer `from carpeta1.subcarpeta1.archivo1 import *`. Ten en cuenta de no agregar espacios al nombre del módulo a importar, ni a las subcarpetas.

Otra forma es usar [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib), que además permite resolver el problema de nombres de módulos con puntos u otros caracteres que invalidan un `import` tradicional. Supongamos que tenemos una rutina `fun_en_archivo_py()` en `code/carpeta1/subcarpeta1` podemos desde `main.py`hacer lo siguiente:

```
import importlib.util

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("archivo", "../carpeta1/subcarpeta1/archivo.py")
archivo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(archivo)
# Para invocar la rutina anteponemos el nombre del módulo
archivo.fun_en_archivo_py()
```

Lo que sí, esto es funcional si no entiendo mal desde la version Python 3.5+ o superior.

Comment: Funcionó perfecto, ahora tengo una pequeña duda, tengo un directorio que contiene puntos en su nombre (porque es una web, uso de nginx, es algo así como testing.web.com), en ese caso cómo podría hacerlo? Porque al poner los puntos lo tomatía como si fueran 3 directorios, verdad?

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que agregues esa carpeta al path `sys.path.append("../carpeta.con.puntos") y hagas un simple `from modulo_en_carpeta_con_puntos import *`.

Comment: Probé lo de importlib pero no me reconoce el util, alguna idea?

Comment: Que versión de Python usas? `importutil` se implementó a partir de la 3.1.

Comment: 3.5 pero tengo instalada la 2.7 también, cómo sé cuál usa mi script?

Comment: Si esto `import sys;assert sys.version_info >= (3,1)` te da un `AssertionError`, quiere decir que estás con una versión anterior a la 3.1

Comment: Ningún error...

Comment: Bien, te sugiero que armes otra pregunta,  con el código mínimo para reproducir el error que tienes con importlib, va a ser más fácil responderte de esta forma.

Comment: Luego de este código spec = util.spec_from_file_location("LoginTest", "../ISV1/testing/LoginTest.py");    archivo = util.module_from_spec(spec);    spec.loader.exec_module(archivo);    LoginTest.test();   obtengo NameError: name 'LoginTest' is not defined. No entiendo por qué

Comment: Yamila, habría que ver el código de `LoginTest.py`. Hay una clase que se llama `LoginTest`?

Comment: Sí hay una clase, este es el comienzo del archivo, hay algo mal? soy bastante nueva en python) 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import unittest
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display


class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):

Answer (score 1):

en code:

```
from carpeta1.subcarpeta1.archivo import *
```

pero en cada carpeta y subcarpeta debes agregar un archivo `__init__.py` (puede estar vacio).
El principal uso de `__init__.py` es inicializar paquetes de Python. Aunque puede estar vacio como dije antes, es util para que la importacion de modulos y paquetes quede mas visible y ordenada. Te sugiero que invesitgues eso.
Saludos!

Comment: El archivo __init__.py está en todas las carpetas y subcarpetas, probé u solucion y aún así sigue sin encontrar el módulo. El archivo desde donde lo quiero llamar se encuentra en la carpeta 2