# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'publications'

Tags: python

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de importar un módulo desde una subcarpeta. Por más que intente de muchas formas no logro conseguirlo.
Esta es mi estructura de ficheros:

```
ml-price-updater
    ├── main.py
    ├── publications
        ├── initiate_internal_data.py
        ├── models
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── models.py
        │   
        │      
        ├── mysql
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── mysql_commands.py
        │   ├── mysql_services.py
        │   ├── proof.py
```

Desde el archivo "proof.py", que fue generado para hacer pruebas, intento importar la clase "Users" del archivo "models" en la carpeta "models".
Al hacerlo, obtengo este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/valen/Escritorio/projects/ml-price-updater/publications/mysql/proof.py", line 1, in <module>
    from publications.models.models import Users
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'publications'
```

El archivo models.py:

```
import uuid
class Users():
    def __init__(self, email, password, uid = None):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.uid = uid or uuid.uuid4()

    def to_dict(self):
        return vars(self)
```

El archivo proof.py:

```
from publications.models import models

user = Users('user@email.com', 'password123')

print(user.to_dict())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys

sys.path.append("..")

from models.models import Users
```

Una forma de resolverlo es usar `sys.path.append("..")`, que añade el path especificado a la lista de paths donde python busca los modulos a importar.

Una vez agregado, ya puedes entrar en la carpeta `models` e importar la clase `Users` del archivo `models.py`. Para ello, escribe `from models.models import Users`.

De otra manera, se puede ejecutar `sys.path.append('../..')` que agregara un path mas "profundo" y asi poder importar de una manera mas clara, asi como:
`from publications.models.models import Users`

[Más información](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/132410/importar-modulos-python-desde-otro-directorio)

Comment: Funciono fantástico. Aunque estuve viendo el post que dejaste al final de la nota y me di cuenta que al ejecutar dos veces "sys.path.append('..')" solo estamos agregando el mismo directorio dos veces, esto lo pude comprobar al ver la lista de directorios con "sys.path". Muchas gracias Angel!!

Answer (score 0):

Yo probaría a crear un archivo **init**.py dentro de la carpeta publications e importar User desde proofs.py con from models.models import User