# Python - Llamar módulos ubicados en otro folder

Tags: python, vscode

Tengo esta estrucutra en mi proyecto de Python.

Desde el archivo **test.py** quiero mandar llamar la clase **GlobalVar** que se encuentra en el archivo **global_var.py** que a su vez, está en otra carpeta: **conn**

Al ejecutar el archivo **test.py** me marca el error de que no se encuentra el módulo **conn**

¿Qué me hace falta?

[image: Python code]

Comment: Buen día, antes de crear una publicación revisa en publicaciones anteriores. Este tema se ha respondido múltiples veces, por ejemplo: [Cómo importar módulos .py de subcarpetas a carpetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1087/c%c3%b3mo-importar-m%c3%b3dulos-py-de-subcarpetas-a-carpetas), [Importar modulos python desde otro directorio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132410/171630)

Comment: Si quieres ejecutar el archivo directamente, (como script) aun siendo parte de un paquete, la forma mas simple es usar un import relativo `from  ..conn.global_var import GlobalVar` y ejecuta el script con `python -m data_admin.tests.test` desde  la terminal, situada  en el directorio padre de data_admin. Los import relativos solo funcionan dentro  de paquetes. Otras formas "menos ortodoxas" son modificar el PATH o usar importlib, mirate [la respuesta de Patricio Moracho](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132603/15089) de una de las preguntas que te enlaza HeytalePazguato.

Answer (score 0):

Has intentado importar con un path python?

```
import sys


sys.path.append('/ruta/de/la/carpeta')
```